# Spring SimpleFormController with annotations in referenceData

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How can i write referenceData method with SpringFormController annotations.I have several java.util.Map objects ,Finally i am setting all these objects in coomand object.How to return this object by using Spring Form Controller.
Initially I am displaying form using below code:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String initForm(Model map){

TestDTO test=new TestDTO();
map.attribute("cmdtest",test);
return "test";

}
@ModelAttribute("customer")
public Model setup(Model map,HttpServletRequest request)
{
   Map testData=testService.getTestData(request)

 model.addAttribute("testData",testData);
return model;
}
```

How to access testData map object in my jsp page?
Regards,

Raj

Comment: Your question's title is misleading. Perhaps rename it to something like "Spring controller annotations" or "How to access Spring model objects in jsp"

Answer (score 0):

The map is available to the jsp page as customer.testData; "customer" because that's what you named your ModelAttribute and "testData" because that's what you named it in the model.

```
<p>Here is your testData: ${customer.testData}</p>
```